# Python - 3D slicer & grey and white data retrieval from a image

Tags: image-processing, functional-programming, mean-stack

I have to do a project, where I have to analyse an image and get the data (white matter and gray matter) from that image and then have to plot 3 slicer of that brain image.

Now I have installed OpenCV and numpy and matplotlib in pycharm.. And  I am using windows platform, will you please anyone help me to finish the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used slicer for tissue classification. It is not very accurate. I suggest you to start using Expectation Maximization (EM) and define a 3 class tissue for your gaussians.

If you have access to PMOD software, it has a very nice tool for classification in brain data.

Answer (score 0):

To gain insight on your data, may be you could download the program 3D Slicer (https://download.slicer.org), then you should be able to load your image. Since it supports a wide range of format (DICOM, nrrd,  nifti, any many more), you should be able to load it.

Then to "analyze" yourself, you could leverage the embedded python interpreter and access the numpy array corresponding to the volume.

See https://www.slicer.org/wiki/Documentation/Nightly/Developers/Python_scripting#Accessing_Volume_data_as_numpy_array

It also includes a broad set of modules to process, transform, segment, register your images. The tutorial available here should be helpful: https://www.slicer.org/wiki/Documentation/Nightly/Training

It may also be sensible to as your question on the associated forum: http://discourse.slicer.org/

Comment: Thank you so much.. I don't have any vision about 3D slicer, but now it's cool.., I believe I made it soon as possible, have to extract white matter and grey matter in python and then only I can give data set to 3D slicer right.

Comment: Do you have any link to that python code, I mean gray matter and white matter extraction from brain MRI

Comment: Automatically extracting gray and white matter is a very difficult problem. Depending on your dataset, different methods would have to be used. Searching through the literature should give you an idea of the different approaches.

To move forward, you should be able to load your data directly in Slicer, then go to the "Segmentation" module and start with a thresholding method.

Comment: Also considering that Slicer is a full fledged library and application built on top of open source libraries like the Insight Segmentation and Registration Toolkit (ITK) (https://itk.org/), Visualization Toolkit (VTK) (https://www.vtk.org/), Qt and Python, it is not possible to provide a simple script.